# Python Pandas Group By Multiple Columns against One Same Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group by multiple columns against the same one column.

Here is the code I already have, which is very repetitive and want to reduce.

```py
result_df.groupby(['main', 'a']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'b']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'c']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'd']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'e']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'f']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'g']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'h']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'i']).size()
result_df.groupby(['main', 'j']).size()
```

I would also prefer to avoid using a loop if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `result_df.set_index('main').stack().groupby(level=(0,1)).value_counts()`?